# simple HTML file parser with php

Tags: php, html, file, parsing, domdocument

I have a particular problem which I can't crack. I searched for every tutorial or form entries, but had no luck in succeeding in what I need to do. So my HTML file:

```
<html>
 <head>**SOMETHING HERE**</head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <table>
    <thead>
  <tr><th>TEXT/NUM IS HERE</th><th>TEXT/NUM IS HERE</th><th>TEXT/NUM IS HERE</th></tr>
    </thead><tbody>**SOMETHING HERE**</tbody></tfoot>**SOMETHING HERE**</tfoot>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

What I need is to go through every tag (th) in the "thead=>tr" tag and record the value between these "th" tags into an array;

For this I was planning to use DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

There was many ways I tried to solve this issue, but most found one online was:

```
$file = "index.html";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLfile($file);
$thead = $dom->getElementsByTagName('thead');
$thead->parentNode;
$th = $thead->getElementsByTagName('th')
echo $th->nodeValue . "\n";
```

But I'm still getting many errors and can't find a way to do this. Is there any way of doing this nice end simple and of course foreach element in the parent element.

Thank you.

Comment: *getElementsByTagName*. Elements. Not element, but elements. It returns an [DOMNodeList](http://dk1.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) as specified by the manual. You need to iterate through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$html = new file_get_html('file.html');
$th = $html->find('thead th');
$array = array();
foreach($th as $text) 
    $array[] = $th->innertext;
?>
```

This uses the Simple HTML Dom Parser which can be found [here.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Use [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$html = <<<EOL
<html>
    <head>**SOMETHING HERE**</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>TEXT/NUM IS HERE</th>
                        <th>TEXT/NUM IS HERE</th>
                        <th>TEXT/NUM IS HERE</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>**SOMETHING HERE**</tbody>
                <tfoot>**SOMETHING HERE**</tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
EOL;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//table/thead/tr/th');

$data = array();

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $data[] = $node->textContent;
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it in the same style as what you have (and therefore learn what you did wrong) try this:

```
$file = "index.html";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLfile($file);

$oTHeadList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('thead');

foreach( $oTHeadList as $oThisTHead ){

    $oThList = $oThisTHead->getElementsByTagName('th');

    foreach( $oThList as $oThisTh ) {

        echo $oThisTh->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
}
```

Basically "getElementsByTagName" returns a NodeList instead of a Node, so you have to loop over them to get to the individual nodes.

Additionally, in your HTML you have a closing `tfoot` instead of an opening one, and if you test using the html document you provided then the `**SOMETHING HERE**` inside your head tag will cause warnings to be thrown (as will any other invalid HTML).

If you want to suppress the warnings an loading you can add an '@', but it's not a good idea to pepper that symbol too much around your code.

```
@$dom->loadHTMLfile($file);
```